# Editing of Android EditText containing text throws NPE on BlackBerry Z10

Tags: android, blackberry, qnx

I got a bunch of identical exceptions from a BlackBerry Z10 device using the Android Runtime 4.3. Whenever the user edits an EditText that already contains a text, the app crashes. Editing an empty EditText works fine. I don't own a BlackBerry device, so I'm unable to verify the crash.

Does anybody have an idea what happens here and how to solve or workaround the problem?

Here comes the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.Editor$QnxInsertionHandleView.<init>(Editor.java:3874)
    at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.getQnxHandle(Editor.java:4885)
    at android.widget.Editor.updateCursorsPositions(Editor.java:1577)
    at android.widget.TextView.getUpdatedHighlightPath(TextView.java:4916)
    at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:5103)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13962)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12856)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12898)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3060)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12793)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12898)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3060)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12793)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12898)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3060)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12793)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12898)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3060)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12793)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12898)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3060)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12793)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12898)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3060)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12793)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12898)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3060)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12793)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12898)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3060)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12793)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12898)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3060)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12793)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12898)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3060)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12793)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12898)
    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1411)
    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1359)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2367)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2239)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1872)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5491)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5116)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Update Oct 31, 2014:**

The evaluation revealed that the app doesn't crash when

- the EditText is empty or
- the EditText contains a text AND "selectAllOnFocus" is set AND the user starts typing, i.e. overwrites the existing text.

The app crashes when

- the EditText contains a text AND "selectAllOnFocus" isn't set or
- the EditText contains a text AND "selectAllOnFocus" is set AND the user positions the cursor inside the EditText (without overwriting the text before).

Comment: Which BlackBerry 10 version was running the devices? 10.3 or 10.2?

Comment: @Jorge It's running 10.3, but the user told me that it's not the final official version.

Comment: This is still happening to me with version 10.3.1. Any known fix?

Comment: @Gaëtan Sorry, no news here.

Comment: @stefan222 Could you find the answer?

Comment: No, sorry, no news here.